# Unexpected unterminated subpattern in regex using Python 3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I've got a verbose regex expression in python 3 to catch windows file paths. Catches optional drive volume, then characters, backslash, more characters one or more times, then optional file extension.

```
(
    (
        ([A-Za-z]:)
        (\\){1,2}
    )?                      # group to catch optional drive volume
    (
        ([A-Za-z0-9_%~\-])* # catch some letters/symbols
        (\\)                # catch one backslash
        ([A-Za-z0-9_%~\-])* # catch more letters/symbols
    )+                      # at least one of this group
    (
        \.[a-zA-Z]{3,4}
    )?                      # catch optional file extension
)
```

As far as I can see, all of the brackets are terminated but I still get an unterminated bracket error on line 3, column 17.

```
  File "C:\Users\mrea\Documents\Result Fingerprinting\lineidentifier.py", line 282, in identify_line
    for match_obj in re.finditer(reg, line, re.VERBOSE):
  File "C:\Users\mrea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\re.py", line 230, in finditer
    return _compile(pattern, flags).finditer(string)
  File "C:\Users\mrea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\re.py", line 286, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Users\mrea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "C:\Users\mrea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\sre_parse.py", line 930, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "C:\Users\mrea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\sre_parse.py", line 426, in _parse_sub
    not nested and not items))
  File "C:\Users\mrea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\sre_parse.py", line 816, in _parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, sub_verbose, nested + 1)
  File "C:\Users\mrea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\sre_parse.py", line 426, in _parse_sub
    not nested and not items))
  File "C:\Users\mrea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\sre_parse.py", line 819, in _parse
    source.tell() - start)
re.error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 31 (line 3, column 17)
```

I tried this all in one line and it threw this error, so I made it verbose to check and I can't see what's wrong.

I'm assuming this is some python specific syntax stuff that I don't know about yet. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Use a raw string literal: `re.compile(r"...", re.X)`.

Comment: To amplify the above comment, if you are not using a raw string, the double backslash becomes just a single backslash in the string and therefore when interpreted by the regex compiler is escaping the following `)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are some regex string options when doing expanded regex.

The easiest to read in the source is *Type 3* the triple quotes **"""**,
however this requires escaping the string as if its a single quote, meaning
even escapes must be made odd.

You can do this with this formula:
`num_esc_to_add = (actual_num_escapes - 1)`

Example:

```
raw       \  :     \\  :      \\\  :         \\\\  :           \\\\\ :             \\\\\\
quote   ' \  :    \\\  :    \\\\\  :      \\\\\\\  :       \\\\\\\\\ :        \\\\\\\\\\\'
```

==========================

***Type 1:***

```
>>> import re
>>> expression1 = '     \n\
...   (                          # (1 start)     \n\
...        (                          # (2 start)     \n\
...             ([A-Za-z]:)                # (3)     \n\
...             (\\\){1,2}                  # (4)     \n\
...        )?                         # (2 end), group to catch optional drive volume     \n\
...        (                          # (5 start)     \n\
...             ([A-Za-z0-9_%~\-])*        # (6), catch some letters/symbols     \n\
...             (\\\)                       # (7), catch one backslash     \n\
...             ([A-Za-z0-9_%~\-])*        # (8), catch more letters/symbols     \n\
...        )+                         # (5 end), at least one of this group     \n\
...        (                          # (9 start)     \n\
...             \.[a-zA-Z]{3,4}     \n\
...        )?                         # (9 end), catch optional file extension     \n\
...   )                          # (1 end)     \n\
... '
>>> Rx= re.compile(expression1, re.X)
>>> print(expression1)

  (                          # (1 start)
       (                          # (2 start)
            ([A-Za-z]:)                # (3)
            (\\){1,2}                  # (4)
       )?                         # (2 end), group to catch optional drive volume
       (                          # (5 start)
            ([A-Za-z0-9_%~\-])*        # (6), catch some letters/symbols
            (\\)                       # (7), catch one backslash
            ([A-Za-z0-9_%~\-])*        # (8), catch more letters/symbols
       )+                         # (5 end), at least one of this group
       (                          # (9 start)
            \.[a-zA-Z]{3,4}
       )?                         # (9 end), catch optional file extension
  )                          # (1 end)
```

***Type 2:***

```
>>> import re
>>> expression2 = "     \n\
...     (                          # (1 start)     \n\
...           (                          # (2 start)     \n\
...                ([A-Za-z]:)                # (3)     \n\
...                (\\\\){1,2}                  # (4)     \n\
...           )?                         # (2 end), group to catch optional drive volume     \n\
...           (                          # (5 start)     \n\
...                ([A-Za-z0-9_%~\\-])*        # (6), catch some letters/symbols     \n\
...                (\\\\)                       # (7), catch one backslash     \n\
...                ([A-Za-z0-9_%~\\-])*        # (8), catch more letters/symbols     \n\
...           )+                         # (5 end), at least one of this group     \n\
...           (                          # (9 start)     \n\
...                \\.[a-zA-Z]{3,4}     \n\
...           )?                         # (9 end), catch optional file extension     \n\
...      )                          # (1 end)     \n\
... "
>>> Rx= re.compile(expression2, re.X)
>>> print(expression2)

    (                          # (1 start)
          (                          # (2 start)
               ([A-Za-z]:)                # (3)
               (\\){1,2}                  # (4)
          )?                         # (2 end), group to catch optional drive volume
          (                          # (5 start)
               ([A-Za-z0-9_%~\-])*        # (6), catch some letters/symbols
               (\\)                       # (7), catch one backslash
               ([A-Za-z0-9_%~\-])*        # (8), catch more letters/symbols
          )+                         # (5 end), at least one of this group
          (                          # (9 start)
               \.[a-zA-Z]{3,4}
          )?                         # (9 end), catch optional file extension
     )                          # (1 end)
```

***Type 3:***

```
>>> import re
>>> expression3 = """
...      (                          # (1 start)
...           (                          # (2 start)
...                ([A-Za-z]:)                # (3)
...                (\\\){1,2}                  # (4)
...           )?                         # (2 end), group to catch optional drive volume
...           (                          # (5 start)
...                ([A-Za-z0-9_%~\-])*        # (6), catch some letters/symbols
...                (\\\)                       # (7), catch one backslash
...                ([A-Za-z0-9_%~\-])*        # (8), catch more letters/symbols
...           )+                         # (5 end), at least one of this group
...           (                          # (9 start)
...                \.[a-zA-Z]{3,4}
...           )?                         # (9 end), catch optional file extension
...      )                          # (1 end)
... """
>>> Rx= re.compile(expression3, re.X)
>>> print(expression3)

     (                          # (1 start)
          (                          # (2 start)
               ([A-Za-z]:)                # (3)
               (\\){1,2}                  # (4)
          )?                         # (2 end), group to catch optional drive volume
          (                          # (5 start)
               ([A-Za-z0-9_%~\-])*        # (6), catch some letters/symbols
               (\\)                       # (7), catch one backslash
               ([A-Za-z0-9_%~\-])*        # (8), catch more letters/symbols
          )+                         # (5 end), at least one of this group
          (                          # (9 start)
               \.[a-zA-Z]{3,4}
          )?                         # (9 end), catch optional file extension
     )                          # (1 end)
```

***Type 4:***

```
>>> import re
>>> expression4 = (
... r"          " + "\n"
... r"     (                          # (1 start)     " + "\n"
... r"          (                          # (2 start)     " + "\n"
... r"               ([A-Za-z]:)                # (3)     " + "\n"
... r"               (\\){1,2}                  # (4)     " + "\n"
... r"          )?                         # (2 end), group to catch optional drive volume     " + "\n"
... r"          (                          # (5 start)     " + "\n"
... r"               ([A-Za-z0-9_%~\-])*        # (6), catch some letters/symbols     " + "\n"
... r"               (\\)                       # (7), catch one backslash     " + "\n"
... r"               ([A-Za-z0-9_%~\-])*        # (8), catch more letters/symbols     " + "\n"
... r"          )+                         # (5 end), at least one of this group     " + "\n"
... r"          (                          # (9 start)     " + "\n"
... r"               \.[a-zA-Z]{3,4}     " + "\n"
... r"          )?                         # (9 end), catch optional file extension     " + "\n"
... r"     )                          # (1 end)     " + "\n"
... )
>>> Rx= re.compile(expression4, re.X)
>>> print(expression4)

     (                          # (1 start)
          (                          # (2 start)
               ([A-Za-z]:)                # (3)
               (\\){1,2}                  # (4)
          )?                         # (2 end), group to catch optional drive volume
          (                          # (5 start)
               ([A-Za-z0-9_%~\-])*        # (6), catch some letters/symbols
               (\\)                       # (7), catch one backslash
               ([A-Za-z0-9_%~\-])*        # (8), catch more letters/symbols
          )+                         # (5 end), at least one of this group
          (                          # (9 start)
               \.[a-zA-Z]{3,4}
          )?                         # (9 end), catch optional file extension
     )                          # (1 end)
```

Comment: Ahh I see, thankyou. I didn't realise using multiline strings affected the way symbols are escaped too.

Comment: In 'type 4' don't the backslashes only need to be single backslashes, as they aren't treated as a special character in a raw string?

Comment: Oh no. With a single backslash it would escape the closing parenthesis in regex. My bad.